# Passing actions and states via props in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to react and redux. I am trying to separate my Component into Container and Presentation Component.
So far, I managed to separate them by passing the actions and states as a props from the Container to the Component.

Here is how they look like:

Container:

```
class HelpForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      help: { message: "" }
    };

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <HelpFormUI actions={this.props.actions} helps={this.props.helps} />
    );
  }
}

HelpForm.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  helps: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};


function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
  return {
    helps: state.helps
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(helpActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HelpForm);
```

Presentation:

```
onClickPost(event){
      this.props.actions.createHelp(this.state.help);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>What can you help today?</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onMessageChange}
          value={this.state.help.message} />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Post"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.onClickPost} />
      </div>
    );
```

My question is: Is it okay to pass the actions and states as props to the children? If no, what is the correct way? I am also wondering, how can I access the parent's state without passing it to children as a props?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll toss out a couple caveats: I'm not 100% certain I follow your example, since you left a lot of the presentation component out, and I don't really understand the benefit of factoring the "UI" out from the container really at all, but with that said, your implementation doesn't seem unreasonable to me.  You could [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) `HelpFormUI` instead, but it seems like that's all the container is doing for you, so I'm assuming you're trying to avoid that.

The way to access a parent's state in a child without passing them as props would be to fire an action to update `state`, and `connect`ing the child.